# pattern matching on a list of lists in haskell

Tags: haskell

I want a function that takes a list of lists of numbers and computes the maximum of each inner list to return a list of numbers. Here's my implementation:

```
f :: [[Int]]->[Int]
f x:xs = (maximum x) : f xs
```

This results in a parse error:

```
h.hs:8:1: error: Parse error in pattern: f
  |
8 | f x:xs = (maximum x) : f xs
```

What is wrong with my code? What is the right way to implement such a function?

Comment: Why not `map maximum`?

Comment: The fact that it says there is a parse error on the `f` token is mysterious for me - but correctly using parentheses: `f (x:xs)` makes it work. (Well, it does once you've replaced the undefined `as` by the obviously intended `x`)

Comment: @RobinZigmond Recall `p:q` is a pattern whenever `p` and `q` are. Here however `p = f x` which is not a valid pattern since in patterns you can't apply variables like `f`. This is why the error is on `f`, I think.

Comment: @Elmex80s Sorry that was a mistake.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Haskell you may use constructor operator as pattern only when it is surrounded by brackets:

```
f :: [[Int]] -> [Int]
f (x:xs) = (maximum as) : f xs
```

Comment: I corrected that and now it says "unexhausted pattern". So I added f [[]]=[] but the problem persists.

Comment: @TrevisLiu Use `f [] = []`

Comment: @4castle But f takes elements of type [[Int]]? So how would it accept []?

Comment: `[]` can have type `[[Int]]`. All list types have `[]` as a constructor.

Comment: @TrevisLiu, more specifically, `[[]]` is a list with *one* element, and that element is the empty list. Whereas `[]` has no elements at all